# Migrating MOSS 2007 site to WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to migrate a site from MOSS 2007 environment to WSS 3.0 environment as it does not (need to) use MOSS features. Unfortunately the site was created using "Publishing" site template. I have gone through the pain of deactivating all the MOSS related features but there still seems to be some MOSS stuff hanging about. TargetTo and ExemptField columns are two of them and they seem to reference Microsoft.Office.Policy.dll and Microsoft.Office.Server.dll respectively.

The work around I have done to get the import working is to manually transfer the two dlls and the field definitions. So I have two questions.

1.What do I do to avoid the work around and actually deactivate them?

2.Is it "legal" to go live with the work around as a WSS environment?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to migrate all the content to a new team site based on one of the WSS templates.  This new team site needs to be in a Site Collection that is based on WSS template, and using a separate Content Database - you'll then join that Content Database to your WSS Farm.

Once you have your new Team Site, you can save your Document Libraries as templates, with the content included, then create new Document libraries based on these templates.  With any luck WSS will handle the MOSS columns gracefully.  If not, perhaps you can just delete them.

Any content based on Pages you will probably have to manually recreate as web part pages in the WSS team site.

Once you have this working ok, you detach the Content DB from the WSS farm, and attach it to the MOSS farm.

I think this is worth trying.  It may also be possible to change the template a site is based on, which may work too, but I think requires some programming skill.